# Managing Document Versions for Multiple Tenses

Tags: tenses, version-control

I need to create two versions of a document, one in future tense and one in past tense:

Document A: *The consultant will do X.*

Document B: *The consultant did X.*

In the past, I've handled this by writing document A, then editing a copy into document B. This creates problems when making major changes; I can try to modify both documents simultaneously, or I can just edit document A and recreate B.

Neither of those approaches seem very efficient. Are there any well-established processes or patterns to handle this challenge? Is there a term to describe this scenario? Just knowing the right terminology would help me in researching this.

Comment: Are all the changes from "will do" to "did", or will other verbs need to be changed as well?

Comment: There are many verbs. That was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

With some tools, you can tag the two verb forms as conditional text in the source document and then render the version you want in the output.

If you're writing a status report, I recommend using verb forms that let you sidestep revising/conditionalizing text, as shown here.

Example A

- Consultant writes blog post. Completed.
- Client publishes blog post. In progress.

Example B

- Consultant: Write blog post. Completed.
- Client: Publish blog post. In progress.

Comment: Finding tools that support conditional text is a significant topic. Some versions of MS Word support "variable substitution" as does LibreOffice Writer: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Variables